# Display a built list of widgets in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a list of widgets I've built with a `for in` loop within a function but I'm unsure as how to display all the widgets as children of a column.

The function `displayAllCards()` builds the list, each widget starts with `padding`, i don't know if that helps or not.

Here's a very stripped down version of my unworking code.

The function to build a widget:

```
Widget displayCard(String bitCurrency) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 0),
    child: Text("$bitCurrency"),
  ); 
}
```

And then I built another function to create a list of widgets throwing in different `bitCurrencies`:

```
List displayAllCards() {
  List<Widget> cards = [];
  for (String bitCurrency in cryptoList) {
    cards.add(displayCard(bitCurrency));
  }
  return cards;
}
```

And finally the output with the Flutter is where I'm dying.

```
body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      displayAllCards(),
    ],
  ),
```

I kinda know why it's not working, but I'm unsure how to make it correct.

I'm fairly new to Dart so please be gentle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use spread operator (...)

```
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...displayAllCards(),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Woah why is this so simple !?